# why conditional search of string values in DataFrame all not work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kaggle

```py
train = pd.read_csv('train_revised.csv')

print(train[train['class of worker'] == 'Private'])
```

the output supposed to show all the results that the column 'class of worker' includes 'Private', but the dataframe is all empty.

[image]

Comment: check if your spelling is correct -- columns or values inside them might have spaces etc. check with: `train.columns` and `train["class of worker"].unique()`

Comment: Thank you, man!!! It solves the issue!!!